# Can we upgrade to tomcat 10 with servlet 3.0?

Tags: tomcat

we have our monolith application hosted with tomcat vision 8 and servlet version 3.0 . We are looking forward to upgrade it to tomcat 10. Is it mandatory to upgrade the servlet version or can we still start the application with prior servlet version?